# C++ Programming Tic Tac Toe AI attempt

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I've tried to look into the already existing codes for Tic Tac Toe, and found out there's an algorithm called MiniMax, although I've understood how it works, I can't seem to make it work using 5*5 table for Tic Tac Toe.

I've an idea of how I'll do it, but I can't seem to find an approach for it.

I'm trying to make a check for every 4 moves in 1 col/row/diagonals so that there's a win there, or there's a block if it's the other player. but I can't seem to find how I can do that, I've been working on it for the past 6 hours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

  char arr[5][5];
char player1 = 'X';
char player2 = 'O';
char player = player1;
using namespace std;
void display() {
  cout << "     1  " << "2  " << "3  "<<"4  "<<"5  " << endl;
  cout << "    ----------------" << endl;
  for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    cout << row + 1 << " |  ";
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      cout << arr[row][col] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
void new_turn();
int firstEmptyRow(int c){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(arr[i][c])
            return i;
    }
}
int firstEmptyCol(int r){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(arr[r][i])
            return i;
    }
}
bool canWin(int mat[5][5]){

    int row,col;
    int countSteps;

    // FOR VERTICAL |
    //trying to find a count of 4 moves in 1 row, so It can be won.
    for(row=0;row<5;row++){
            countSteps=0;
        for(col=0;col<5;col++){
            if( (arr[row][col] == arr[row+1][col])
               &&(arr[row][col] ==player2)){
                countSteps++;
            }
        }
        if(countSteps==4){ cout << "MOVE IS WIN-ABLE" << endl; return true;}
    }

    return false;


}
int computer_move(){
    char temp;
    int test[5][5], tempo[5][5];
    int row, col;
    for(row=0;row<5;row++){
        for(col=0;col<5;col++){
                test[row][col] = arr[row][col];
                 tempo[row][col] = arr[row][col];
        }
    }
    for(row=0;row<5;row++){
        for(col=0;col<5;col++){
            if(arr[row][col] == '-'){
                temp = arr[row][col];
                if(canWin(test)){ // an attempt to test the move


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void player_move() {
if(player==player1){
  int his_moveRow, his_moveCol;
  cout << "please enter your move row player " << player << endl;
  cin >> his_moveRow;
  cout << "please enter your move col player " << player << endl;
  cin >> his_moveCol;

  if (his_moveRow < 0 || his_moveRow > 5 || his_moveCol < 0 || his_moveCol > 5) {
    cout << "please enter a number from 1 to 5 player " << player << endl;
    player_move();
  }
  --his_moveRow;
  --his_moveCol;
  if (arr[his_moveRow][his_moveCol] == '-') {
    arr[his_moveRow][his_moveCol] = player;
  } else {
    cout << "please try again player " << player << endl;
    player_move();
  }
}else{
//computer move!!
cout <<"Computer Move!"<< endl;
computer_move();
}
  if (player == player1) {
    player = player2;
  } else {
    player = player1;

  }
  new_turn();
}
bool check_win();
void new_turn() {
  display();
  if (check_win() == true) {
    cout << "congratulation player " << player << " you won!" << endl;
    return;
  } else {
    int row, col, count = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
      for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        if (arr[row][col] != '-') count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == 25) {
      cout << "No one won. That's a draw." << endl;
      return;
    } else {
      cout << "next turn" << endl;
      player_move();
    }
  }

}
bool check_win() {
  //Vertical |
  int row, col;
  for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      if ((arr[row][col] == arr[row + 1][col] && arr[row + 1][col] == arr[row + 2][col])
          &&(arr[row+2][col] == arr[row + 3][col] && arr[row + 3][col] == arr[row + 4][col])
          && arr[row][col] != '-') {
        cout << "player won" << endl;
        player = arr[row][col];
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  //Horizontal -
  for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      if ((arr[row][col] == arr[row][col + 1] && arr[row][col + 1] == arr[row][col + 2])
         &&(arr[row][col+2] == arr[row][col + 3] && arr[row][col + 3] == arr[row][col + 4])
          && arr[row][col] != '-') {
        cout << "player won" << endl;
        player = arr[row][col];
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
      //Diagonal "\"
        row=0,col=0;
    if((arr[row][col] == arr[row+1][col+1] && arr[row+1][col+1] == arr[row+2][col+2]
        && arr[row+2][col+2] == arr[row+3][col+3])
    &&(arr[row+3][col+3] == arr[row+4][col+4]) && arr[row][col] != '-'){
         cout << "player won" << endl;
        player = arr[row][col];
        return true;
    }


  // Diagonal " / "
  for (row = 4; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      if ((arr[row][col] == arr[row - 1][col + 1] && arr[row - 1][col + 1] == arr[row - 2][col + 2]
           && arr[row - 2][col + 2] == arr[row - 3][col + 3]
           && arr[row - 3][col + 3] == arr[row - 4][col + 4]) && arr[row][col] != '-') {
                cout << "player won" << endl;
                player = arr[row][col];
                return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
void game_start() {
  for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
      arr[row][col] = '-';
    }
  }
  display();
  player_move();

}
int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  game_start();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use recursive routine to make the function easier. Also you make use of alpha beta pruning to make the search tree smaller and increase the depth of search. Some end winning moves can be used for comparison at the leaf nodes.

Answer (score -1):

I once did something similar, though not using that MiniMax algorithm. I used a comic "guide" from xkcd that tells about optimal tic tac toe moves.
If your program follows this, you can never lose, only win or tie.

https://xkcd.com/832/